# Book recommendation & reference request: Old analysis books

Tags: analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for old analysis books. By old I mean very old, like very early 20th century and before (yes, eighteenth century counts).

It is indifferent to me if it has exercises or not.

I only ask for a good coverage of the most important topics we study today and a good emphasis on infinite series.

Also, I have a preference for books written originally in Latin or English (German is ok, but less desired).

Thank you. I hope it is not asking too much.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you particularly interested in old books?

Comment: Try Cauchy's Cours D'Analyse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse

Comment: @Favst Thank you for your suggestion, Favst.

Comment: @littleO I prefer far more the writing of old authors, in general. And let me admit that I have almost a fetish for the antique.

Comment: If you are familiar with latin, you shouldn't have much difficulty reading books written in french. There are a lot of them, some very didactic like E. Bezout, "Cours de mathématiques, à l'usage de la marine et de l'artillerie" (that Napoleon mastered). I could list easily 20 of them...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your suggestion, Jean Marie. Yes, I haven't much problems with french, I just forgot to mention this one, even because I didn't expect it to be the language with the highest quantity of works satisfying my request. Feel free to add more, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @JeanMarie By the way, Jean, it doesn't have to be particularly didactic. It can even be written as a first exposition of the subject to scholars. If I don't understand it, I will keep it with me and try again after some time. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fundamental books written in French. You can have electronic access to many of them through "gallica". Like you, I am interested by these old books (and have purchased some of them).

- A. Cauchy: "Cours d'Analyse" (already mentionned by Favst)
- in the same vein, different lectures given at "Ecole Polytechnique" that were *lithographed* (in order that each student has his own copy of the lecture notes). Those of
- C. Hermite: (1873) "Cours d'Analyse"
- C. Jordan (1882) same title (recently re-edited https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cours-danalyse-de-lecole-polytechnique/0A83F049A98167EFA3C41DE1CDD03F05) and
- J. Hadamard (1912) same title
- E. Bezout: "Cours de mathématiques, à l'usage de la marine et de l'artillerie" (edition 1798, first edition around 1775) https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6212877w/f8.image.texteImage
- Abbé C. Bossut: "Cours de mathématiques" (1781).
- M. Chasles: "Aperçu historique sur l'origine et le développement des méthodes en géométrie" (1837)
- P. S. Laplace: "Traité analytique des probabilités" (1812)
- Marquis de l'Hôpital: "l'analyse des infiniments petits pour l'intelligence des lignes courbes" (1696)
- J. Ozanam: "Dictionnaire de mathématiques" (1691)
- Descartes: "La géométrie" (1637)
  (very good analysis of this fundamental book [here](http://caphi.univ-nantes.fr/IMG/pdf/Descartes-Geometrie.pdf)) which encompasses in fact all the premisces of what will become "Analysis" a century or so later.

(List to be extended)